# Grails Quartz - Jobs are running even when nothing is scheduled

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have defined a job as follows in the jobs folder in grails:

```
class TransferFilesQueueJob {

  def execute() {
    print "File Transfer Job start!"
    FileTransfer.transferFilesToHere()
    print "File Transfer Job end!"
  }
}
```

When running my application in IntelliJ, this job runs every few seconds or so.  Even after restarting.  Any idea why?  I don't have any other places that are scheduling it.

I had a declaration earlier on, but I've removed it.  It seems like it is storing configuration somewhere else or job state information.  But I cannot find where.
-- Further notes
I renamed the job class and it stopped running.  So this seems to point to the job being persisted somewhere.  However, I have never set it to have any kind of persistance beyond the current running of the server.

Comment: Are there any active Run tabs at the bottom in IntelliJ? Or shutdown IntelliJ and try. Maybe it is holding on to some process in the background.

Comment: I've restarted by intellij and the computer with no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Quartz plugin has a default simple trigger for every `Job`, which is used if no trigger is set by the programmer, and which fires every few seconds.  To have no triggers attached to a `Job`, set an empty `static triggers` block in the class.

```
static triggers = { }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought there must be some kind of default.  But I didn't know how to override it.  Thanks again!